# Getting User Object from Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, in my app I have a game lobby where a user makes a game, and then another user joins the game. When a user makes the game, they are stored in the Database as `user1` in the proper node, and when a user joins the game, they are saved as `user2` in the same node. Here they have their information stored, like shown below.

[image]

The database information in the picture is the Lobby version of the data, and whenever a second valid user joins the game, I want this database to be deleted (because it is being drawn as an interface and I don't want other users to join a full game) and I want it to be made into a new 'active game' database.

I know how to do this, but I am wondering how I can move `user1` and `user2` as User objects over to the new database. I have tried to create a callback for these items as User objects but I have had a lot of issues with that so I am hoping there is another way to go about this.

Right now, once the `user2` field exists in a node, this method to create the game is called:

```
private void createGame(String gameID) {
    FCGames.child(gameID).removeValue();
    FCGameMaker fc = new FCGameMaker(null, null, false, false, gameID);
    FlipCoinGames.child(gameID).setValue(fc);
    startActivity(new Intent(FlipCoinLobby.this, FlipCoin.class));
}
```

I have `null` set in place for the User objects because I do not know how to get the user objects from the old database into this new one. This is my FCGameMaker constructor so you can understand that a little bit better.

```
public FCGameMaker(User player1, User player2, boolean gameStarted, boolean gameFinished, String gameId) {
    this.player1 = player1;
    this.player2 = player2;
    this.gameStarted = gameStarted;
    this.gameFinished = gameFinished;
}
```

Here is how my `user1` field is created whenever somebody makes a game

```
public void createLobbyGame () {
    final User user1 = new User(userName, 0, null, FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid(), gameID);
    AlertDialog.Builder fcDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    fcDialog.setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface fcDialog, int which) {
            double wager = Double.parseDouble(wagerText.getText().toString());
            //creating the game
            FCLobbyMaker gameMaker = new FCLobbyMaker(user1, null, wager, gameID,
                    false, false);

            FCGames.child(gameID).setValue(gameMaker);
        }
    });

}
```

There is more to that last method I Just deleted some unnecessary code because there is quite a bit in that method.

Can anyone help?

Here is the, what I believe is inefficient, workaround for this problem.. Creating a new user object by retrieving each data point separately

```
private void createGame(final String gameID) {
    FCGames.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DataSnapshot ds1 = dataSnapshot.child(gameID).child("user1");
            DataSnapshot ds2 = dataSnapshot.child(gameID).child("user2");
            String userName = ds1.child("userName").getValue().toString();
            String HorT = ds1.child("horT").getValue().toString();
            String uid = ds1.child("uid").getValue().toString();
            String userName2 = ds2.child("userName").getValue().toString();
            String HorT2 = ds2.child("horT").getValue().toString();
            String uid2 = ds2.child("uid").getValue().toString();

            User user1 = new User(userName, 0, HorT, uid, gameID);
            User user2 = new User(userName2, 0, HorT2, uid2, gameID);

            FCGameMaker fc = new FCGameMaker(user1, user2, false, false, gameID);
            FlipCoinGames.child(gameID).setValue(fc);
            startActivity(new Intent(FlipCoinLobby.this, FlipCoin.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    FCGames.child(gameID).removeValue();
}
```

Comment: I somewhat solved my problem by just getting each user value separately and creating a new User object. Shown at the bottom of the post. I am wondering now if there is a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I think you can sayUser user1 = ds1.getValue(User.class);